# C , Reading from a text file and using scanned Character in boolean expression in If Else Statement

Tags: c

I have to scan values from a text file:

```
D 5000
C 200
```

where the D equals deposit into a checking account and C equals a withdrawal, and display the balance in the account after each transaction. My variable `transactionType` takes the value of the character correctly, but when I use an `if`/`else` statement for the required formula to calculate account balance, it won't work. How can I use the `if`/`else statement correctly? I tried using 67 as ASCII value; I've tried 'C' for the withdrawal.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char transactionType;
    double transactionAmt;
    double accountBalance = 0.0;
    FILE *fpIn, *fpOut;

    fpIn = fopen("transactions.txt", "r");

    if (fpIn == NULL)
    {
            printf("Input file is having issues while opening");
    }

    fpOut = fopen("processed.txt", "w");

    if (fpOut == NULL)
    {
            printf("Output file is having issues while opening");
    }

    printf("Welcome to Russell's Checking Account Balance Program\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    fscanf(fpIn, "%c %lf\n", &transactionType, &transactionAmt);

    printf("The Transaction is a: %c and the amount is: %lf\n", transactionType, transactionAmt);

    if (transactionType = 'C') {

            accountBalance = accountBalance - transactionAmt;
    }

    else  {
            accountBalance = accountBalance + transactionAmt;


    }

    printf("The Balance in your checking account is: %lf\n", accountBalance);


    fclose(fpIn);
    fclose(fpOut);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you've got an assignment in your `if`, not just a comparison.  This is a common problem for people who've used other languages where `=` is used for equality testing — and it is easily overlooked by beginners who've not programmed in any language before.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong operator:

```
if (transactionType = 'C') {
```

Will assign transaction type to 'C' and return true always.

```
if (transactionType == 'C') {
```

Will test to see if the transaction type is 'C'.  Common mistake :-)

Oh, and while you don't have this problem, it's worth reiterating that "C" (a string) is not the same thing as 'C' (a char), so

```
foo == "C"
```

Isn't particularly useful (use strncmp() or similar instead).

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it! That did it.